# What Mono version to use

Tags: mono

I'm starting a new project that'll require Mono and mod_mono to run under CentOS. There are two versions of Mono: the release which is 2.10.8, and the development branch, which is 3.0.7 as of today.

I'm wondering what would be the right version to start. Obviously the stable version would be my choice, but I'm not sure what Mono 3.0 adds that could be missing from 2.10. Note that the project will be ASP.NET 4.0, using MVC4.

What version would be recommended? The stable but older one (dates back from 19-Dec-2011!) or the more recent one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mono 2.10 supports ASP.NET MVC3, since you want to use MVC4, you'll have to use a later version.
More recent versions of Mono have solved a lot of issues in 2.10, including issues related to ASP.NET.

So you may want to go for a more recent version. I don't think stability will be an issue,
but you will have to perform proper tests to determine if the version you are using supports everything you are trying to do in your application.

Don't deploy to production without testing.

UPDATE: Correction, there is 'partial' MVC4 support in 2.10 and no support for async.
So while you might be able to use 2.10, your mileage may vary depending on what features your app uses